# how to replace a string using sed with a string in a file

Tags: sed

I want to replace a string with a string from a file. 
Suppose I have this string and I want to replace the string, inside `<start></start>`, with the string in `temp.out` file. I want do do this because the string I am trying to substitute is very very long so I want to save the string in a file and load the string from the file using sed.

```
<start><value1></value1><value2></value2></start>

temp.out // suppose temp.out has a very very very long string
<value1></value1><value2></value2><value1></value1><value2></value2><value1></value1><value2></value2><value1></value1><value2></value2><value1></value1><value2></value2><value1></value1><value2>... </value1><value2></value2><value1></value1><value2></value2><value1></value1><value2></value2>
```

Comment: so you want `<start>contents of temp.out</start>` ? What is the significance of `replacing`? Why you can not just append `<start>` and `</start>` with the contents of `temp.out`, e.g. `echo "<start>\`cat temp.out\`</start>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string=`cat temp.out`
string=${string/|/\\|/} # Change any | in $string to \|
sed "s|<start>.*</start>|<start>$string</start>|" oldfile > newfile
```

Comment: why can not you do the way I suggested in the comment above? It is much simpler...if there is no significant of `replacing`

Comment: I assume because this isn't the only thing in the original file.

Comment: could you please explain what the 2nd line does?

Comment: I've added a comment explaining what it does. It's needed to prevent a `|` in the file from acting as a delimiter to the `s|||` command.